# Translation of idiomatic "so" expressions in Spanish

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

How would one translate the "so" in the following expressions:

> I am so loving it.
>
> You are so screwed.
>
> This is so not good.

I know "so" translates as `tan` but will this literal translation work in the above scenarios? Are the following sentences correct:

> Estoy tan amandolo.
>
> Estás tan cogido.
>
> Este tan no está bueno.

Comment: Estoy amándolo tanto. Es incorrecto decir "estoy tan amándolo". Por otra parte, decir "Estás tan cogida" no tiene sentido en la muy noble y muy leal lengua española. Nosotros no estamos pensando siempre en lo mismo, como los estadounidenses; y cuando en ello pensamos, no lo proclamamos impúdicamente a los cuatro vientos. Ni siquiera los franceses, que intentan seguir siendo finos en toda circunstancia, pase lo que pase.

Comment: "[screwed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80890/is-im-screwed-a-rude-expression)" is not very rude; you can say it on TV. The literal equivalent in Spain ("jodido"), is way more rude (in TV I'd say 18+ rated films). You will definitely hear it in a bar, and likely in an informal conversation between colleagues. "Cogido" is purely South American, and I don't really know how they take it, but I believe it is of similar or greater rudeness. I think a closer translation would be "la he cagado", or, if in respectable company, "la he fastidiado".

Comment: Thanks, Davidmh. It´s true we say "jodido"; but never "cogido" whose meaning is "taken", in Spain. Anyway i misunderstood "screwed" for it sexual meaning. In the sense you explained it it´s still better to say "la hemos liado; la he liado" yet in a slang mode. Sorry for my deficient English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no translation, that I can think of.  Using the word "so" in your given context is using it as a multiplier.  One is not just screwed, but rather sooo... screwed.

> This food is good!

vs

> This food is sooo good!

*The extra o's indicate the prolonged stretching of the vowel*

The closest thing to that in Spanish is with superlatives, `riquisisisisimo`.

> ¡Esta comida está rica!

vs

> ¡Esta comida está riquísima!

... adding more `si`s to stress it more.

http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/52

EDIT

It may only be regional to Mexico, but another way to translate it would be with `bien` instead of `tan` as you've tried in your OP.

> You are *so* screwed.
>
> Estás *bien* cogido.

Comment: Unfortunately this method only works if "so" is qualifying an adjective. But it doesn't work with sentences like I presented (e.g., "I'm so loving it") where it qualifies a verb instead. It also doesn't seem to work with constructs like "this is so not good."

Comment: Yes unfortunately,... though there is another method, check my update.

Comment: As for the `McDonald's-esque` phrase `I'm so.. lovin' it,`  you're only going to get by with `Estoy amándolo mucho`

Comment: _Estás_ bien cogido.  Or, for Spanish from Spain: Estás bien jodido

Answer (score 2):

Let's check them case by case:

> Estoy tan amandolo.

You can't use *tan* before a gerund, so you must put it at the end instead. This forces you to use *tanto*, instead of the *tan* apocopation.
On the other hand, "*Estoy amándolo*" sounds a bit odd to begin with, as you'd probably say "*Lo amo*" on a normal context.

Correct form:

> Lo amo tanto.

---

> Estás tan cogido.

This is actually fine. Just take into account that *cogido* is a regionalism, and in Spain it wouldn't mean what you expect.

For Spain, you would use:

> ¡Estás tan jodido!

---

> Este tan no está bueno.

This is the hardest one. You can't use *tan* before a negative, so the only correct variation with "tan" here would be something like: "*Este no está tan bueno*", but it would have the opposite meaning of what you wanted (ie: instead of "*This is so not good.*", it would mean "*This is not so good.*").

The best option for this one would be to change the phrase so you don't need the *no*. For example:

> Esto está tan malo.

---

Finally, to answer dockeryZ's edit,

> ¡Esta comida está tan rica!

is commonly used, at least in Spain.

Comment: In Spain, "coger", always takes in the plain.That is: "coger" does mean "to take"  and not a sexual meaning. Same thing in  France : "prendre" has the meaning ot "to take" though there is a band in Portland, Pink Martini, i guess; they sing some songs in french with "prendre" = "to take" with this old meaning; a poem from Apollinaire, i think. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeVJbhXuRek

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6E-B5RQUbE

Answer (score 2):

En Colombia,  la palabra que usamos equivalente a *so* en inglés y en el **mismo contexto**, es **tan**.

> This is so good! => *¡Esto es tan bueno!*
>
> Your parents are so lovely! => *¡Tus padres son tan queridos!*
>
> She is so hot! => *¡Ella es tan buena!*
>
> He is so grumpy! => *¡Él es tan gruñón!*

Comment: Gracias por todas estas respuestas. Ten en cuenta que la ortografía es importante, así que sería bueno que añadieras tildes en tus respuestas : )

Answer (score 2):

Las traducciones directas a lo que quieres decir serían:

> I am so loving it. - Lo estoy amando tanto.
>
> You are so screwed. - Estás tan jodido./Estás bien jodido.
>
> This is so not good. - Esto es tan malo.

Answer (score 1):

Curiosamente, en español, también se utiliza el ***so***, para potenciar las cualidades del adjetivo o del nombre a que antecede:

---

> *"I am so loving it."*
>
> *"You are so screwed."*
>
> *"This is so not good."*

---

- Pido disculpas si doy una mala traducción, pero intentaré hacerlo
  bien.

> *"Estoy **so** enamorado de eso."*
>
> *"Estás **so** liado."*
>
> *"Esto no es nada bueno."*

Claro que no se utiliza normalmente, pero es valido.

---

- Ahora sí lo que buscas es un uso más cotidiano, sería:

> *"Eso me tiene muy enamorado."*
>
> *"Estás bastante jodido."*
>
> *"Esto no es nada bueno./Eso esta muy mal."*

---

***Fuente:*** [***so***1. RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=so)